# How can I export the raw body of a node?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I set up a CSV view with `views_data_export`. I'd like to export the raw body of nodes. So I want to keep both the raw markdown and the raw HTML in the CSV.

Is there a way to do this that I have overlooked? Should I add a formatter that does nothing? If so, how can I do that?

[image]

[image]

---

I thought I had solved it by checking "Rewrite the output of this field" and using `[body-value]`, which is the raw value.

[image]

And this gives me the raw markdown but still doesn't give me the raw HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **FORMAT**, click on **Settings**, check mark "Keep HTML Tags"

[image]